# Solving environment: failed

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I want to install Tensorflow-GPU for Anaconda Python 3.6.

How can I fix this?

```
$  conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu 
Solving environment: failed

# >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ERROR REPORT <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 819, in __call__
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 78, in _main
        exit_code = do_call(args, p)
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/conda_argparse.py", line 77, in do_call
        exit_code = getattr(module, func_name)(args, parser)
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 11, in execute
        install(args, parser, 'install')
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 235, in install
        force_reinstall=context.force,
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 518, in solve_for_transaction
        force_remove, force_reinstall)
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 451, in solve_for_diff
        final_precs = self.solve_final_state(deps_modifier, prune, ignore_pinned, force_remove)
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 180, in solve_final_state
        index, r = self._prepare(prepared_specs)
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/solve.py", line 592, in _prepare
        self.subdirs, prepared_specs)
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 215, in get_reduced_index
        new_records = query_all(spec)
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/index.py", line 184, in query_all
        return tuple(concat(future.result() for future in as_completed(futures)))
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 95, in query
        self.load()
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 149, in load
        _internal_state = self._load()
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 218, in _load
        mod_etag_headers.get('_mod'))
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 280, in _read_local_repdata
        _internal_state = self._process_raw_repodata_str(raw_repodata_str)
      File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/conda/core/subdir_data.py", line 369, in _process_raw_repodata_str
        info['fn'] = fn
    TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

`$ /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/bin/conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu`

  environment variables:
                 CIO_TEST=<not set>
               CONDA_ROOT=/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3
              CONDA_SHLVL=0
               MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles
                     PATH=/scratch2/system/opt/pycharm-community-2018.1.2/bin:/scratch2/google-
                          cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/
                          anaconda3/bin:/scratch2/system/opt/pycharm-
                          community-2018.1.2/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-
                          sdk/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda//anaco
                          nda3/bin:/scratch2/system/opt/pycharm-
                          community-2018.1.2/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-
                          sdk/bin:/scratch2/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/scratch/sjn/anaconda/bin:/usr/
                          lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bi
                          n:/sbin:/usr/local/IT/bin:/home/grad3/jalal/bin:/scratch/sjn-p2/anacon
                          da/anaconda2/bin
               PYTHONPATH=:/scratch2/body_pose/tf-
                          openpose/src/tensorpack:/scratch2/body_pose/tf-openpose/src/tensorpack
           QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib64/kde4/plugins:/usr/lib/kde4/plugins
       REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=<not set>
            SSL_CERT_FILE=<not set>
               WINDOWPATH=1

     active environment : None
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /home/grad3/jalal/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/grad3/jalal/.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : 3.2.2
         python version : 3.6.4.final.0
       base environment : /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3  (read only)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/noarch
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
          package cache : /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/pkgs
                          /home/grad3/jalal/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/grad3/jalal/.conda/envs
                          /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.4 Linux/3.10.0-862.14.4.el7.x86_64 centos/7 glibc/2.17
                UID:GID : 275735:3935
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False


An unexpected error has occurred. Conda has prepared the above report.
If submitted, this report will be used by core maintainers to improve
future releases of conda.
Would you like conda to send this report to the core maintainers?
[y/N]: y
Upload successful.

Thank you for helping to improve conda.
Opt-in to always sending reports (and not see this message again)
by running

    $ conda config --set report_errors true
```

Using pip I get the following error:

```
[jalal@goku pset3_CNN]$ pip install tensorflow-gpu
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/25/52/01438b81806765936eee690709edc2a975472c4e9d8d465a01840869c691/tensorflow_gpu-1.11.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting gast>=0.2.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting tensorboard<1.12.0,>=1.11.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/2f/4d788919b1feef04624d63ed6ea45a49d1d1c834199ec50716edb5d310f4/tensorboard-1.11.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting protobuf>=3.6.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/f9/28787754923612ca9bfdffc588daa05580ed70698add063a5629d1a4209d/protobuf-3.6.1-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting keras-applications>=1.0.5 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3f/c4/2ff40221029f7098d58f8d7fb99b97e8100f3293f9856f0fb5834bef100b/Keras_Applications-1.0.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools<=39.1.0 in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting absl-py>=0.1.6 (from tensorflow-gpu)
Collecting keras-preprocessing>=1.0.3 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fc/94/74e0fa783d3fc07e41715973435dd051ca89c550881b3454233c39c73e69/Keras_Preprocessing-1.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting astor>=0.6.0 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/35/6b/11530768cac581a12952a2aad00e1526b89d242d0b9f59534ef6e6a1752f/astor-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting grpcio>=1.8.6 (from tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/9c/523fec4e50cd4de5effeade9fab6c1da32e7e1d72372e8e514274ffb6509/grpcio-1.15.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8 (from tensorboard<1.12.0,>=1.11.0->tensorflow-gpu)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/6b/5600647404ba15545ec37d2f7f58844d690baf2f81f3a60b862e48f29287/Markdown-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorboard<1.12.0,>=1.11.0->tensorflow-gpu)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py in /scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.5->tensorflow-gpu)
Installing collected packages: gast, protobuf, markdown, grpcio, tensorboard, keras-applications, termcolor, absl-py, keras-preprocessing, astor, tensorflow-gpu
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gast'
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[jalal@goku pset3_CNN]$ sudo pip install tensorflow-gpu
[sudo] password for jalal: 
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-gpu in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: mock>=2.0.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.0 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.13.3)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (0.14.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.2.0 in /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages (from tensorflow-gpu) (3.5.2.post1)
Requirement already satisfied: funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3" in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow-gpu) (1.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr>=0.11 in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from mock>=2.0.0->tensorflow-gpu) (3.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.2.0->tensorflow-gpu) (0.9.8)
rtslib-fb 2.1.63 has requirement pyudev>=0.16.1, but you'll have pyudev 0.15 which is incompatible.
matplotlib 2.2.2 has requirement python-dateutil>=2.1, but you'll have python-dateutil 1.5 which is incompatible.
bleach 2.1.3 has requirement html5lib!=1.0b1,!=1.0b2,!=1.0b3,!=1.0b4,!=1.0b5,!=1.0b6,!=1.0b7,!=1.0b8,>=0.99999999pre, but you'll have html5lib 1.0b8 which is incompatible.
You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
[jalal@goku pset3_CNN]$ python -c "import tensorflow"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `conda install python=3.6 tensorflow-gpu`.

(I tried it in `anaconda3-5.2.0`.)

Comment: The problem was with `-c anaconda`; this channel should not be used any more.  See [this comment](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7875#issuecomment-431627284) on conda GitHub issue #7875.